# Casting columns in SQL with joins

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this large and confusing sql query I'm trying to run, however some of the columns need to be casted as different types. Here is my query as of now:

```
SELECT PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYTYPEID, PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYGROUPID, PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYVALUE, TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYGROUPID
FROM PROPERTY_DATA
INNER JOIN TEMPLATE_PROPERTYGROUPS
  ON PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYGROUPID = TEMPLATE_PROPERTYGROUPS.PROPERTYGROUPID 
  INNER JOIN TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES
  ON PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYGROUPID = TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYGROUPID
  INNER JOIN TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS
  ON TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYUNIT = PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYGROUPID
```

The `TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYUNIT` is a string and I'm trying to link it with an int value. But I'm not sure how to cast it the right way :/

Comment: Look into the function "CAST"

Comment: Can you cast with a join function though or is it just with a single select statement?

Comment: Ideally it should be possible but I've never come across such a situation so can't tell you for sure

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the value stored in the string will always be numeric whole number you can do one of the following

```
SELECT CAST(TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYUNIT AS INT) FROM TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS

SELECT CONVERT(INT, TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYUNIT) FROM TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS
```

An example with joins

```
SELECT *
FROM PROPERTY_DATA   
INNER JOIN TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS ON 
    CAST(TEMPLATE_PROPERTYUNITS.PROPERTYUNIT AS INT) = PROPERTY_DATA.PROPERTYGROUPID
```

Comment: But would I be able to do this within the joins as well or is this just with a single select statement?

Comment: Yes you can do it within the joins as well. Ill update my answer with that as well.

Comment: Sorry this took me so long to respond. But when I add the cast to the join it still says `Invalid Number`